# Difference between WhatsApp and Signal implementation of the Open Whisper Protocol

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, protocol-design, signal-protocol

WhatsApp has taken the step of using the Open Whisper Protocol for their message encryption, borrowed from the Signal application.

I was wondering if there was any obvious, high level, difference in the implementation of the Open Whisper Protocol between these two mobile phone applications? For example, Perhaps Signal is using HMAC as part of their design, whereas WhatsApp is not?

This question focuses on the implementation, from a highish level, without going into the mathematics too far. Diagrams are often helpful.

Comment: There is a canonical question/answer of our [SEJPM](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/71460/sejpm) on information security [Is Signal still more secure than WhatsApp?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/139493/86735). I don't think that we need a dupe here. Or maybe SEJPM can copy and paste their answer.

Comment: @kelalaka I just had a quick skim read. IIRC Signal uses some type of hashing, whereas WhatsApp takes a different approach. Focusing from a fairly high level, non-mathematical, there are clearly some differences between their implementation...